# undefined offset after using array_unique

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i am using array_unique(); to unique array values it perfectly works.
but when if getting value form offset it gives error. mission offset.

my array before using array_unique();

```
$tags_array = explode(',', $tagss);
```

it gives result :

> Array ( [0] => katha [1] => pooja [2] => singer [3] => katha [4] => katha [5] => pooja [6] => archana [7] => dance )

after using array_unique();

```
$tags_array = array_unique($tags_array);
```

it gives result :

> Array ( [0] => katha [1] => pooja [2] => singer [6] => archana [7] => dance )

i am using it in loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($tags_array);$i++){
    echo '<a class="label label-primary tags" href="'.base_url().'home/tag/'.$tags_array[$i].'">'.ucfirst($tags_array[$i]).'</a>';
}
```

it gives error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 3
>
> Filename: views/search.php
>
> Line Number: 178

how to make serial wise offset. like

> Array ( [0] => katha [1] => pooja [2] => singer [3] => archana [4] => dance )

Answer (score 0):

do the fact that you have not more the array index based on sequential number 
instead  of for you could use foreach

```
foreach($tags_array as $key => $value{
   echo '<a class="label label-primary tags" href="'.
         base_url().'home/tag/'.$tags_array[$i].'">'.
             ucfirst($value).'</a>';
}
```